# Converting two numbers into one in C

Tags: c, numbers

newbie question;
I have two binary numbers; say for example; 0b11 and 0b00. How can I combine the two numbers so that I get 0b1100 (i.e. place them right next to each other to form a new number)

Comment: Is `0b11` meant to be a binary literal? C doesn't have that feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With bitwise shift and or operators:

```
unsigned int a = 0x03;  /* Binary 11 (actually binary 00000000000000000000000000000011) */
unsigned int b = 0x00;  /* Binary 00 */

/* Shift `a` two steps so the number becomes `1100` */
/* Or with the second number to get the two lower bits */
unsigned int c = (a << 2) | b;

/* End result: `c` is now `1100` binary, or `0x0c` hex, or `12` decimal */
```

Comment: @elyashiv Nothing, but I prefer to use the bitwise operators when working with bits.

Answer (score 2):

Shifting left `<<` and bitwise OR `|`:

```
int a = 0;             /* 0b00 */
int b = 3;             /* 0b11 */
int c = (b << 2) | a;  /* 0b1100 */
```

Notes:

- The OR is not needed though, because `a` is 0 in this case.
- The `2` in the shift operator means "shift two bits to the left". Shifting right is the `>>` operator.